# Inequality $p_n<n\left(\log n + \log\log n\right)$

Tags: number-theory, inequality, reference-request, prime-numbers

Wikipedia told me this bound (which of course holds true if $n\ge6$) for the $n$-th prime is due to Bach and Shallit, and I found "Eric Bach and Jeffrey Shallit: Algorithmic Number Theory, Volume I: Efficient Algorithms, MIT Press, August 1996.", can you confirm? If that's correct, what theorem is it? I went through what Google allowed me to read, but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book you mention appears to be a textbook; I do not think there is an implication that the result is due to Bach and Shallit, merely that it (possibly) can be found there.

Anyway, a better bound $p_n<n\left(\log n + \log\log n - 1/2 \right)$ was already established by Rosser and Schoenfeld in 1962.

You can find a nice overview on progress on bounding the $n$-th prime [on a page of the TME-ETM project](http://math.univ-lille1.fr/~ramare/TME-EMT/Articles/Art01.html).

Answer (score 5):

In your mentioned book, chapter 8.8: *Some Useful Explicit Estimates*, [page 233](https://books.google.com/books?id=iJx1lP9ZcIkC&pg=PA233), the result is given as *Theorem 8.8.4* without a proof. As a reference, **Rosser and Schoenfeld [1962]** is given. In the bibliography, you can find

[Rosser and Schoenfeld 1962]: 
J.B. Rosser and L. Schoenfeld. [Approximate formulas for some functions of prime numbers](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1255631807). Ill. J. Math. 6 (1962), 64-94.